# Find largest payee in a table

Tags: excel, max

I have a finance tracker in excel with some sample data that I'm trying to find stats about.

each transaction has fields shown

[image: in this picture]
How would I find the largest payee based on the amounts in column D (eg. who paid me the most money).

I can find the sum of one payee using index and sumif: (finances2019 being the transaction table)

```
=SUMIF(INDEX(Finances2019,,8),"Cisco",(INDEX(Finances2019,,4)))
```

But how can I search through the sum of each one and find the max?

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(Finances2019,MATCH(MAX(D:D),D:D,FALSE),8)
```

I think this should work. 
Might not be the best way though.

Edit:
Just tried it and it doesn't like D:D as a full column. You have to use D2:D (whatever row it stops at).

Comment: This formula seems to just find the max in column D, I'm looking for the max out of the totals for all the payees. (eg. the sum my bank paid me this year is $200, sum my job paid me is $25,000, sum I made from ebay sales is $2,000. I'm looking for the max of those sums.)

Comment: Strange that it is only returning the max figure in column D, it's working this end. The formula looks in column D for the max, then returns the name on that same row from column H, in this case "Cisco", which is the output you are looking for, unless I am misunderstanding what the output you want is.

Comment: Sorry just realised what you actually want, it's been a long day. You want to find the sum of all transactions from each payee, then out of those sums which payee paid the most?

Comment: Precisely, yes.

Comment: It's a tricky one without vba, the only way I can think is nested if functions. It isn't practical or elegant...

Comment: =IF(MAX(SUMIF(H:H,"TD",C:C),SUMIF(H:H,"Remax Ltd",C:C),SUMIF(H:H,"Jamie",C:C),SUMIF(H:H,"Cisco",C:C))=SUMIF(H:H,"TD",C:C),"TD",IF(MAX(SUMIF(H:H,"TD",C:C),SUMIF(H:H,"Remax Ltd",C:C),SUMIF(H:H,"Jamie",C:C),SUMIF(H:H,"Cisco",C:C))=SUMIF(H:H,"Remax Ltd",C:C),"Remax Ltd",IF(MAX(SUMIF(H:H,"TD",C:C),SUMIF(H:H,"Remax Ltd",C:C),SUMIF(H:H,"Jamie",C:C),SUMIF(H:H,"Cisco",C:C))=SUMIF(H:H,"Jamie",C:C),"Jamie",IF(MAX(SUMIF(H:H,"TD",C:C),SUMIF(H:H,"Remax Ltd",C:C),SUMIF(H:H,"Jamie",C:C),SUMIF(H:H,"Cisco",C:C))=SUMIF(H:H,"Cisco",C:C),"Cisco",))))